# how to make a Qt text output widget?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

What is the best way to a text based output in a Qt widget? what I mean by this is... like in win RAR or some windows installers where there is a drop down arrow showing more details and it shows live text output of files modified and things of that nature. how would I go about doing that in a Qt app?

I was thinking maybe a none editable multiple line text box... but I'm not sure, because I don't wan't it to be editable.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a [`QTextBrowser`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtextbrowser.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QLabel`

`QTextDocument`

`QTextEdit`

Almost all of the options above, can be configured to be "Read-only" or even unclickable by making them disabled.

`QTextStream` is also a really useful class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very much! QTextEdit is the one i ended up going with. I just had to make it read only and connect the textChanged signal to a method that scrolls to the bottom every time the text changes. so thank you very much this was a huge help.